# How to pack desktop app develop on electron into .exe?

Tags: electron

I have develop a desktop app on electron platform. I want to pack my app into .exe so that it can be installed in all any OS.

Comment: it was very helpful thanks for ur reply. i want to run my app on all platform is there any process to make this happen.it is working fine on window .

Answer (score 4):

1. Install [electron-winstaller](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer)
2. Add new scripts in package.json:

   ```
   "buildWin": "electron-packager AppDir AppName --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --electronVersion=1.4.13 --app-version=1.0.0 --build-version=2.0.0 --icon=./assets/favicon.ico --prune=false --overwrite=true && electron ./package.js"`
   ```
3. Make a file `package.js` and put:

   ```
   var installer = require('electron-winstaller');
   var path      = require('path');
   const dialog  = require('electron').dialog;

   console.log("packaging into a exe...\n");
   resultPromise = installer.createWindowsInstaller({
       appDirectory:    './AppName-win32-ia32',
       outputDirectory: './installers/final',
       exe:             'AppName.exe',
       setupExe:        'FinalExeName.exe',
       noMsi:           true,
       iconUrl:         'IconUrl',
       setupIcon:       'IconPath'
   });

   resultPromise.then(function () {
       console.log("Installer created");
       dialog.showMessageBox({
           type:    'info',
           title:   'electron-winstaller',
           message: "Installer created",
           buttons: ['ok']
       });
       require('electron').app.quit();
   });
   ```
4. Run `npm run buildWin`.
5. After one min it will say `Installer created in electron folder`.
6. Inside there will be an exe.
7. See [electron-winstaller](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer).

Comment: where to add buildWin in package.json file

Comment: @akk Add it in the `"scripts"` section like: `{"scripts": {"buildWin": "electron-packager..."}}` [Read more on npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)